# KeyValuePair type inference inside Dictionary initializer

Tags: c#, dictionary, namespaces, .net-core, type-inference

I'm building a `Dictionary` with key type `KeyValuePair`. When using `KeyValuePair.Create` inside `Dictionary` initializer it doesn't require template types and it inferred the type correctly, the following compiles correctly without even a warning:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<KeyValuePair<Market, MarketData>, string> channelDict =
    new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Market, MarketData>, string> {
        { KeyValuePair.Create(Market.USD, MarketData.Trade), "trades" },
        ...
};
```

Now the code was reorganized, type `Market` and `MarketData` was moved to a separate project and namespace, and the namespace is imported by `using` statements at the top of the file, but now the same code won't compile, it throws this error:

```
error CS0305: Using the generic type 'KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments
```

I can be sure that `using` namespace imported correctly, because simple add `private Market _m;` didn't produce any error, what's more, the definition of the dictionary:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<KeyValuePair<Market, MarketData>, string> channelDict =
    new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Market, MarketData>, string>
```

did not produce error neither, it is the `Create` method cannot compile:

```
KeyValuePair.Create(Market.USD, MarketData.Trade)
```

So why it cannot infer the type now when type arguments is in another namespace, while it can before?

Comment: Looks like you have declared the dictionary as accepting `IDictionary<KeyValuePair<Market, MarketData>`, and are then trying to create a KeyValuePair that is actually different:  `KeyValuePair.Create(Market.USD, MarketData.Trade)`.  Market is not the same Type as Market.USD, and MarketDate is not the same Type as MarketData.Trade

Comment: No, Market is a enum and Market.USD is a value of this enum.

Comment: consider [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: Why is Tuple better than KeyValuePair?

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  I can reproduce this error, but it is because there is no "Create" method for the KeyValuePair.  Instead of `KeyValuePair.Create(Market.USD, MarketData.Trade)`, why can't you just use `KeyValuePair<Market, MarketData>(Market.USD, MarketData.Trade)`

Comment: It's more important to get the root cause for me, it certainly can work with type arguments.

Comment: So is the Create Method an Extension?  If so, where is the code?

Comment: It's in the framework, because I didn't write that method, it's just there when I called it.

Comment: @fluter just because dictionary already is container of `KeyValuePair` and i think it makes no sense to explicitly making a dictionary of `KeyValuePair`, `Tuple` is just to avoid concepts misunderstanding. if your mind is very clear, that's ok. in fact i'd rather making some custom class instead of `KeyValuePair` or `Tuple` if i'm doing such task.

Comment: It's not in the framework I'm using (C#6, .net framework 4.5.2).  It must be a C#7 thing perhaps??  Have you set your project to an older framework?  As noted, I can get this error by typing `KeyValuePair.Create` into the IDE, but that's because it doesn't support a create method, and is looking for a Type identified.

Comment: I just found the issue is in the target framework in project file, it is because some apis are in .netcore but not in .netframework or .netstandard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After done some digging, I just found that the problem is not about initialization of `KeyValuePair`, rather it's because difference of target frameworks.

Initially all the code are in the same .NET Core console app, set target framework as `netcoreapp2.0`, and from the docs, in .NET Core 2.0, [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair?view=netcore-2.0) is a static class with a static method [`Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair.create?view=netcore-2.0#System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_Create__2___0___1_), which will infer the type arguments correctly.

Then when I reorganized the code, I moved this part to a class library, by default, dotnet tool will set `netstandard2.0` as its target framework, however, [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair?view=netcore-2.0) and `Create` is not available in `netstandard2.0`, as you can see from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair?view=netstandard-2.0), it says:

> This API is not supported in the currently selected framework.

That's why the code failed to compile when moved to a library project, there is only generic [`KeyValuePair<K, V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netstandard-2.0) version in `netstandard` framework.

As a workaround, I verified when I set target framework in the .csproj file to `netcoreapp2.0` and `outputtype` to `library`, it succeeded to compile.

OTOH, library project uses netstandard by default because it makes sure the library is usable among different platform targets, so the better fix would be do not use `static KeyValuePair.Create` in library code, and use generic version instead: `new KeyValuePair<K, V>(k, v)`.